# Filtering for multiple criteria in different columns including string and date in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns namely "Status" and "Finish Date". I want to filter for "OPEN" and "CLOSED" in **Status** column first and then filter for "1/0/1900" in **Finish Date** column.

For this I wrote the following code:

```
Dim LR As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With ActiveSheet

        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A1:A" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
            "OPEN", "CLOSED"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Range("A1:A" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array(0, "1/0/1900"), Operator:= _
            xlFilterValues

End With
```

But this did not work. At first I get the Error (AutoFilter Method of Range Class Failed 1004). Then by mistake I removed the 1st line in the With statement(.AutoFilterMode = False) and I did not get any error. However the filter returned no results at all.

I thought that there is something wrong with my date filter since the Status column filter was working earlier. So I researched and wrote the code below for the date filter alone but again it does not work.

```
Dim dDate As Date
Dim strDate As String
Dim lDate As Long, LR As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    dDate = DateSerial(1900, 1, 0)
    lDate = dDate

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & lDate, _
                     Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & lDate + 1
```

Please help in getting these two filters to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you mess things up a little bit

try this

```
Sub Test()
    With ActiveSheet  '<--| reference your sheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove any existing filtering
        With Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its range in columns A:B from row 1 down to column A last not empty row
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("OPEN", "CLOSED"), Operator:=xlFilterValues '<--| filter on referenced range 1st column with "OPEN" or "CLOSED" values
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="1/0/1900" '<--| filter on referenced range 2nd column with "1/0/1900" value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

BTW you'd better substitute `ActiveSheet` with some `Worksheets("mySheetName")` (where you change "mySheetName" to your actual sheet name) since relying on `ActiveSheet` can be misleading

Comment: NICE :) you can remove seoncd row with `LR` as you directly use the last row method inside your `Range`

Comment: @ShaiRado, well `AutoFilter()` can be a little tricky at the beginning.

Comment: @Tarun, did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

TarunS, looks like you are selecting only one column ( Column A ) in the Range() but trying to apply filter in two columns. I have created excel worksheet where column A is "Status" and column B is "Finish Date" and I am able to create filter as you explained with following code:-

```
Dim LR As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With ActiveSheet

    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1:B" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=CLOSED", _
    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=OPEN"
    .Range("A1:B" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="1/0/1900"

 End With
```

Please note that I have equal number of items in Column A and Column B and I am using Excel 2010. Let me know if you still face any problem with the code.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. After multiple tries I got the answer in the end. I am supposed to change the date criteria1 to "<1/1/1900"instead of "1/0/1900" possibly because 1/0/1900 means 0 but this date does not actually exist.

Comment: Thanks for the help @ user3391546!

Comment: looks like your "Finish Date" is formatted to some specific date format. That most be the  reason why you have to do "<1/1/1900" instead of "1/0/1900". In my case I use "Finish Date" as general type instead of any specific date format.

Comment: It could be that. But I haven't specified the date format anywhere. Maybe it is pre-formatted somehow. I am also using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I Consider your data is like as below

```
column A    Column B
Status  Finish Date
OPEN    1/0/1900
CLOSED  1/0/1900
OPEN    1/0/1900
CLOSED  1/0/1900
OPEN    1/0/1904
CLOSED  1/0/1905
OPEN    1/0/1906
CLOSED  1/0/1907
OPEN    1/0/1908
CLOSED  1/0/1909
OPEN    1/0/1910
CLOSED  1/0/1911
OPEN    1/0/1900
CLOSED  1/0/1900
OPEN    1/0/1900
CLOSED  1/0/1900
OPEN    1/0/1900
CLOSED  1/0/1900
OPEN    1/0/1905
OPEN    1/0/1906
CLOSED  1/0/1906
OPEN    1/0/1906
CLOSED  1/0/1906
OPEN    1/0/1906
CLOSED  1/0/1906
OPEN    1/0/1906
CLOSED  1/0/1906
OPEN    1/0/1906
x   1/0/1906
y   1/0/1906
Z   1/0/1906
A   1/0/1906
b   1/0/1906
```

You can Type the formula in  column C (at C2 Cell)

=IF(AND((OR(A2="open",A2="Closed")),B2= "1/0/1900"),"Yes","No")

Drag this formula till last row(last of column A or B)

It will gives you output like below:

```
Status  Finish Date Result
OPEN    1/0/1900    Yes
CLOSED  1/0/1900    Yes
OPEN    1/0/1900    Yes
CLOSED  1/0/1900    Yes
OPEN    1/0/1904    No
CLOSED  1/0/1905    No
OPEN    1/0/1906    No
CLOSED  1/0/1907    No
OPEN    1/0/1908    No
CLOSED  1/0/1909    No
OPEN    1/0/1910    No
CLOSED  1/0/1911    No
OPEN    1/0/1900    Yes
CLOSED  1/0/1900    Yes
OPEN    1/0/1900    Yes
CLOSED  1/0/1900    Yes
OPEN    1/0/1900    Yes
CLOSED  1/0/1900    Yes
OPEN    1/0/1905    No
OPEN    1/0/1906    No
CLOSED  1/0/1906    No
OPEN    1/0/1906    No
CLOSED  1/0/1906    No
OPEN    1/0/1906    No
CLOSED  1/0/1906    No
OPEN    1/0/1906    No
CLOSED  1/0/1906    No
OPEN    1/0/1906    No
x   1/0/1906    No
y   1/0/1906    No
Z   1/0/1906    No
A   1/0/1906    No
b   1/0/1906    No
```

then you can easily set the filter on column c as criteria "Yes"
or if you want to copy the data , set the filter on "yes"

and use the code to copy data

Range("A2:C1048576").specialcells(xlcellTypeVisible).copy Destination:=Range("D2")

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim i As Integer
    
    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
    If Range("B2") = "All" Then
    
      Range("A5").AutoFilter
      Range("A5").AutoFilterMode = False
      Else
        For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count
            Worksheets(i).Range("A5").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Target.Value _
    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=OPEN"
    Worksheets(i).Range("A5")..AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria2:=Range("B2")
            
        Next
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```